# Python dataclass initialization and updating its field

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I just started learning Python and have a question about dataclass initialization and updating its field using a function.

When I run the code below, I was expecting to `second.flags.checked` to be `None`, but I see it set to `True` instead. What is the correct way to initialize a dataclass so that new `Flags` is initialized I create a new `TestClass` in this case?

```
class Flags:
    checked: bool = None


@dataclass
class TestClass:
    test: str
    flags: Flags = Flags()

    def update_flags(self):
        self.flags.checked = True


first = TestClass(test="test1")
first.update_flags()

second = TestClass(test="test2")
print(f"{second.flags.checked}")
```

Comment: Both instances are sharing a single `Flags` instance. In other words `first.flags is second.flags` is True.